# Getting the size of a scrollable data's contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable `scrollbar` that contains >=0 data elements added with `addItemBefore`. When `scrollbar` contains zero elements, a specific event needs to trigger. I have all the working code for `scrollbar` and the event, although I don't know how to check if `scrollbar` contains no data elements.

Relevant code:

`var scrollbar = $("#scrollbar-id").data("scrollable");`

...

`function addElement(message) {`

...

`scrollbar.addItemBefore(message); }`

I'd like to retrieve the number of items in scrollbar inside another function to trigger the  event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `scrollbar.getItems()` and then check the `length`

```
if(scrollbar.getItems().length == 0) { no items } else { items }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try counting the objects in .data()

http://jsfiddle.net/CbugG/1/

```
function count(obj){
    var c = 0;
    for(var p in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) ++c;
        log(obj[p]);
    }
    return c;
}
```